# Why didn't Marco Polo tell the Khan and Kaido about the Crusader's plan?

Tags: marco-polo

In Season 2, Marco Polo captured his father, who told him the plan of Crusaders, to divide and conquer the Mongols by letting the Mongols(Kublai & Kaido) fight each other, then the crusaders will wipe out the winning mongols too.

Kaido and Kublai was having a rift with each other during the kurultai, but they still respect each other. If Marco had told them about the Crusader's plan and their army who's coming to wipe off of Mongols, there would have been a chance that both of them would join forces to defeat the Crusaders.

So, maybe Marco didn't trust his father's words. But after seeing the Crusader's Army Marching towards Karakoram, he went back to save Kublai, who was being choked by Kaido at that time. He knew Kublai's would need his neighbor's alliance to defeat the chainmail-Iron/steel-armour-plated Crusader's army who is marching towards karakoram. He could have knocked off Kaido instead of stabbing him in the back. He could have then told Kaido and Kublai about the plan of Crusader's then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have mistaken the plot (If I am right about it). Marco's Father worked with the pope who sent their men to fight with Kaidu.

The army that Marco sees when he is leaving Karakoram is of Prester John. Prester John is a man that the pope hopes to meet but no one is able to find him. Only Marco's father and Prince Nayan, both were stuck in the desert at two different points of time, were rescued by Prester John.

As for why Marco killed Kaidu, he was saving his king, whose life was in danger and given that it is Kaidu, the only option Marco had was to kill him. 
Had he knocked him down, there is no guarantee that things will end in peace once Kaidu is awake. It is not sure if Kaidu would even believe Marco.

Now that Kaidu is dead, there is no civil war, and at least one army to fight the approaching christian army.

I hope they renew the show for another season. :\